# How to make a python script work with and without arguments (default arguments)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to get a Python script to work regardless when an argument has been passed or not.

The goal is to make the script functional as "MyPython.py" and "MyPython.py 5" should be able to work. If no argument has been passed, then the argument should be 0.

The variable `imported_number` should by default be 0 but if an argument has been detected, then it should take whatever number the user has passed.

```
import argparse

imported_number = 0

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("opt_number", type=int, help="Provide a number please")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.opt_number > 0:
    imported_number=args.opt_number
    print "You provided me with the number " + imported_number
    print "You provided me with the number {}".format(args.opt_number)
else:
    print "You did not provide me with any number. Taking the default value, which is " + imported_number
```

Unfortunately I am getting the `error: too few arguments` error message.

Does anyone know of good and automated methods to get this task done? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried `nargs='?'` in `add_argument` ?

Comment: Set a [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nargs`, `default`, `const` like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("opt_number", type=int, help="Provide a number please",
                    nargs='?', default=0, const=0)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Your `opt_number` will be initialized with 0 when no argument is provided.

Comment: In a `positional` like this, `const`, while accepted as a parameter, does nothing.  You get either the default or the user value.  With an `optional` it is useful, providing a 3 way choice.

Comment: Thanks mate! This was the trick that I was looking for. Simple and functional in any case.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your script a function that accepts an argument passed to it.

```
import sys

def your_function(imported_number=0):
    # your code
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        imported_number=sys.argv[1]
    except:
        pass
    your_function(imported_number)
```